# Error 412 (ConditionNotMet) when using batch http request to add multple aliases to a group

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using batch http requests to add multiple aliases to Google groups. While the first alias for each group is added correctly (response 200), subsequent aliases in the same batch to the same group fail with error 412.

Here is my code:

```
def create_group_aliases(service, aliases_by_group_id):
    alias_return = service.new_batch_http_request()
    for id in aliases_by_group_id:
        alias_list = aliases_by_group_id[id]
        for alias in alias_list:
            alias_return.add(service.groups().aliases().insert(groupKey=id, body={'alias': alias}))
    alias_return.execute()
    return alias_return
```

If I run this:

```
create_group_aliases(service, {'aaatestprime@foo.bar':['alphatest@foo.bar', 'betatest@foo.bar'], 'bbbtestprime@foo.bar':['gammatest@foo.bar', 'deltatest@foo.bar']})
```

My batch response gives me `200 OK` responses for `alphatest@foo.bar` and `gammatest@foo.bar` but I get the below error for `betatest@gfoo.bar` and `deltatest@foo.bar`

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "conditionNotMet",
    "message": "Concurrent email update.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "If-Match"
   }
  ],
  "code": 412,
  "message": "Concurrent email update."
 }
}
```

I get the same behavior when trying to add multiple aliases to a user.

```
def create_aliases(service, aliases_by_user_id):
    alias_return = service.new_batch_http_request()
    for id in aliases_by_user_id:
        alias_list = aliases_by_user_id[id]
        for alias in alias_list:
            alias_return.add(service.users().aliases().insert(userKey=id, body={'alias':alias}))
    alias_return.execute()
    return alias_return
```

Is this a bug or a feature? I can obviously add each alias as a separate job but I would prefer to use batches as they're so much easier to work with and I have several hundred aliases I need to add.